# Swift 4 convert bytes to Int and ntohl

Tags: objective-c, swift, byte

Hey guys so I've been trying to convert this objective-c code to swift but keep stumbling on problems with it. Heres the objective-c code:

```
int msgLength = *((int *) _inputBuffer.bytes);
msgLength = ntohl(msgLength);
```

and heres what I managed to get:

```
var msgLength = (inputBuffer.bytes).load(as: Int.self)
msgLength = Int(NSSwapBigLongToHost(UInt(msgLength)))
```

but this isn't working, it crashes saying there isn't enough bits. I really appreciate the help thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C `int` type is a 32-bit integer (on all current Apple platforms),
whereas the Swift `Int` is 64-bit integer on 64-bit platforms.

Therefore in Swift you'll have to use `UInt32` for 32-bit integers:

```
var msgLength = (inputBuffer.bytes).load(as: UInt32.self)
msgLength = UInt32(bigEndian: msgLength)
```

Or, if you switch from `NSData` to `Data`:

```
let msgLength = UInt32(bigEndian:inputBuffer.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
```

(Even in the C code `uint32_t` would be better suited than `int` to emphasize that 4 bytes are read.)